# Resize element past ScrollViewer bounds

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two user controls: **UserControl A** consist of a *StackPanel nested inside a ScrollViewer*. 
**UserControl B** is basically a row with extra features, one feature is a hover over button which *expands a Grid* to show details.

The problem I am having is, when I add **UserControl B** to **UserControl A** *StackPanel*, the hover over effect cannot *resize* past the ScrollViewers bounds.

**User Control A**

```
<ScrollViewer Width="200" Height="250" Margin="0,25,0,0" ClipToBounds="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel_ContentContainer" ClipToBounds="False">
        <!--User Control B goes here-->
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**User Control B**

```
<Canvas Name="Popup" Panel.ZIndex="50" ClipToBounds="False">
    <Grid Name="Information_Content" Margin="-60,-80,0,0" Width="300" Height="300" Panel.ZIndex="100" ClipToBounds="False">
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Is there a way to resize controls outside of ScrollViewers bounds?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Canvas in User Control B: [It doesn't know how to "auto size" based on its content.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx)

> Canvas is the only panel element that has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has default Height and Width properties of
>   zero, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes
>   its child elements. Child elements of a Canvas are never resized, they
>   are just positioned at their designated coordinates. This provides
>   flexibility for situations in which inherent sizing constraints or
>   alignment are not needed or wanted. For cases in which you want child
>   content to be automatically resized and aligned, it is usually best to
>   use a Grid element.

As MSDN recommend, the easiest way to get around this is to use Grid instead of Canvas.

Comment: The **canvas** allowed the **grid** to expand past the **UserControls** dimensions before introducing the **ScrollViewer**. By removing it and just using the **Grid**, an issue occurs which prevents the **grid** growing larger than the **usercontrol** itself. Which does not fix the issue. 

[With canvas](https://imgur.com/a/QTML5) 
[Without canvas](https://imgur.com/a/Nia91ex)